# Is there a way we can filter blobs that are not in archive tier in Azure Blob?

Tags: blob, azure-data-factory

I have a blob container say "demo". It has many files, few are in hot tier and few are in archive tier. I want to process only those files which are in Hot ignoring archive tier files.

1. using getmetadata activity lists all files including archive tier files
2. using "az storage blob list throws" error - 'This operation is not permitted on an archived blob.'

Pl direct me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List Blobs` operation which returns a list of the blobs under the specified container.

Method: `GET`

Request URI: `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list`

HTTP Version: `HTTP/1.1`

This will return the response body in XML format which you can later filter on the basis of access tier names.

In the above URI, you also need to provide parameter `include={versions=2019-12-12}` if it doesn't use newest version automatically.

> For version 2017-04-17 and above, List Blobs returns the `AccessTier`
> element if an access tier has been explicitly set. For Blob Storage or
> General Purpose v2 accounts, valid values are Hot/Cool/Archive. If the
> blob is in rehydrate pending state then `ArchiveStatus` element is
> returned with one of the valid values
> `rehydrate-pending-to-hot`/`rehydrate-pending-to-cool`.

Refer [List Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check and revert Utkarsh.

Comment: Sure. Do let me know if it works fine.

Comment: Pls give full syntax to include parameter version too

Comment: Needed to mention this in Request Headers (not on the URI itself):  
x-ms-version: 2020-04-08

Comment: Utkarsh, could you please let me know how I can filter only hot tier blobs from the output of this web activity, that completes my question as well?

Comment: As you got the output in XML file, you can store the output in Azure SQL database and query the actress tier column using T-SQL.

Comment: Using which activity I can do that. (Moving records to SQL)

Comment: This looks like client side filtering.  Is there a way to filter by Access Tier in the request (i.e. to hopefully make it much quicker)